# Gitlab job fails if it deletes the build directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job at the end of my GitLab CI pipeline meant to clean up the gitlab-runner's build directory.

It constantly fails, but every step is performed flawlessly. When I replicate this locally by hand, I don't get any errors.

Here's the job in question:

```
cleanup:
    only:
        - triggers
    allow_failure: true
    stage: teardown
    script:
         - docker kill PipeLineContainer_$CI_PIPELINE_ID
         - docker rm PipeLineContainer_$CI_PIPELINE_ID
         - sudo rm -rf /home/gitlab-runner/builds || true
```

When this job runs, this is what the job output shows:

```sh
$ docker kill PipeLineContainer_$CI_PIPELINE_ID
PipeLineContainer_694
$ docker rm PipeLineContainer_$CI_PIPELINE_ID
PipeLineContainer_694
$ sudo rm -rf /home/gitlab-runner/builds || true
bash: ligne 87 : cd: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/5KQvSgfo/0/my_projects/project: No such file or directory
bash: ligne 87 : cd: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/5KQvSgfo/0/my_projects/project: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing this is a bug on GitLab's part? Is there a quick workaround that doesn't involve messing with local files (I rely on runner-side aliases for my pipeline)?

Deleting both root and gitlab-runner's `.bash_logout` files as I saw recommended elsewhere didn't do anything, btw.

Comment: Pretty clear on its face, no? You're deleting a directory that gitlab's wrapper for scripts it generates requires to still exist.

Comment: so, umm, *don't* delete that directory. If your goal is to delete something more specific under that, then do that -- make your `rm -rf` more specific, so it doesn't delete the locations that gitlab expects to still exist.

Comment: (anything that was talking about `.bash_logout` was hogwash; it's not run for noninteractive shells at all -- neither is `.profile` or `.bashrc`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This happens if I a run `rm -rf` in a totally empty directory. I don't think deleting scripts has anything to do with it.

Comment: What I can speak to is the evidence and transcript you provided, which is code that deletes all of `/home/gitlab-runner/builds`, followed by an error message from gitlab (presumably a separate script invoked from the same parent shell) complaining that `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/5KQvSgfo` doesn't exist. Of *course* it doesn't exist; you deleted it. If you want to claim that the same error occurs when you *don't* delete the build directory, [edit] the question to enter a transcript of that case into evidence.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I managed to fix it by just deleting the contents of the build directory, but leaving the directory itself. I have no idea what difference it makes, since the scripts are still executed without issue, but whatever. My guess is that GitLab expects the build directory to exist but whatever is inside the directory itself is of no consequence to GitLab. It was just a mistake on my part, I expected GitLab to basically just run SSH commands on my Runner and decide whether a job fails or passes based on the return codes of the script commands. I suppose I was wrong.

Comment: Exactly right. CI systems typically support archiving build results, and at least doing automated cleanup/maintenance of builds prior to the current one; when you get overaggressive with your own logic for the purpose, it can cause the built in logic to fail.